# TextField onChange not fired

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I'm using TextField in one of my components, but all events work except onChange.

```
<TextField onChange={this._onSectionChange} />
private _onSectionChange= (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | 
HTMLTextAreaElement>): void => {
   alert(event.currentTarget.value);
}
```

From the documentation, it mentions that the interface of onChange event is:

```
(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, 
 newValue?: string) => void
```

but in my code it only accepts:

```
onChange?: (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void
```

I bound the method in constructor, also tried:

`onChange={()=>alert('something!')}`

it's not firing at all!

Answer (score 0):

Check your console for errors, something else might have caused it.

For example: https://codepen.io/mohamedhmansour/pen/pQxOLR

```
<TextField onChange= {(e, text) => this.setState({text})} />
<Label>{this.state.text}</Label>
```